# How to convert for example: (int)5 to (byte)0x05 in Java?

Tags: java, hex, byte

I tried:

```
int amount = 5;
String amountStr = "0x0" + amount;
byte newByte = Byte.parsByte(amountStr);
```

But i get `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x05"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to parse a String, Use [`Byte#decode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29):

```
byte newByte = Byte.decode(amountStr);
```

Otherwise you can just cast it (as written in comment).